# Trying to figure out what's wrong with this SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT P_descript, p_price, v_name 
From Vendor, Product
WHERE p_price > 6.99 AND Vendor.V_STATE IN ('TN')
Inner Join Vendor ON product.v_code = vendor.v_code
ORDER BY p_price DESC;
```

The inner join on this keeps getting underlined in Oracle SQL Developer.  I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with it but I feel like it's correct.  Please help me out.

Comment: `join` comes before `where`

Comment: `select ... from ... join ... where ... order by ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Vendor twice in the statement, first in the from statement and then on the inner join.

Try this :

```
SELECT P_descript, p_price, v_name 
From Product
Inner Join Vendor ON Product.v_code = Vendor.v_code
WHERE p_price > 6.99 AND Vendor.V_STATE IN ('TN')
ORDER BY p_price DESC;
```